# System Time To Server with PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, time

What I'm trying to do, is to fill in a hidden input in a login/register page for a website, and inside that input will contain the JavaScript `new Date()` thing, like:

```
"Fri Mar 23 2012 22:23:03 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

I would like to take that information and use it server-side to convert it to the PHP `date()` and display it  in the user's timezone.

It seems like there would be an easy way using the GMT difference of `-0700`, but I've looked all over and I can't find a way to simply plug that number in.

Is there an easy solution to this? All I want to do is modify the output to the users time after submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [date_create_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or a similar function. Make sure to output the date from Javascript in the same format you intend to read.

Also see this old answer from ... myself:

- [How to show server and user time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093074/1244588)